# Searching through hundreds of columns without naming them?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm accessing SQL through SAS, I'm searching through a table with columns named as such:

```
a1   a2   a3   ...  a500  b1    ...  b500
1022 1025 1184      1011  1085       1542
1965 1547 1242      1354  1874       1745
```

I'm trying to find rows that have two separate codes anywhere in the a* columns, along the lines of:

```
where (a1...a500) like 1022 and (a1...a500) like 1184
```

How do I search all these columns without naming them?

Comment: How are you accessing SQL?  e.g Pass-Through or Libname

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WHICHN()` function to find a value across multiple columns.

```
data want;
  set have;
  where whichn(1022, of a1-a500) and whichn(1184, of a1-a500);
run;
```

If by "SQL" you mean you want to use PROC SQL then this will not work since you cannot use the variable list in PROC SQL code. You could use it in a dataset option instead.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
    select * 
    from have(where=(whichn(1022, of a1-a500) and whicn(1184, of a1-a500)))
  ;
quit;
```

If by "SQL" you mean that your data is not in a SAS dataset, but is instead being accessed from a remote database I doubt that SAS can push that WHERE clause into your remote SQL database.  So SAS will need to pull all the rows over to SAS to be able to apply the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate the columns and produce a list with their names. Then construct the query and pass it to the `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @ColumnList NVARCHAR(1024) = '' -- Adjust the length as need

SELECT @ColumnList = @ColumnList + COLUMN_NAME + ', ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable' AND COLUMN_NAME like 'a%'

SET @ColumnList = SUBSTRING(@ColumnList, 0, LEN(@ColumnList))

--PRINT @ColumnList

DECLARE @Sqltext NVARCHAR(1024) = 'SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE (1022 IN (' + @ColumnList + ')) AND (1184 IN (' + @ColumnList + '))'

--PRINT @SqlText

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlText
```